# python copy files with time stamp

Tags: python, shutil, file-copying

I would like to copy file with date time stamp. the below code is not working on windows. I am new to python so please help me.

```
import shutil
import datetime
shutil.copyfile('C:\\Users\\Documents\\error.log','C:\\Users\\Documents\datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S").log')
```

Comment: Do you mean keep the source file's time stamp?

Comment: `'C:\\Users\\Documents\\{}.log'.format(datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S"))`

Comment: i want that the code should copy  "error.log"  To  "error-datetime.log"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you have the code enclosed in the string. You need to run the code out of the string, and combine it with the string. A solution would be

```
import shutil
import datetime
shutil.copyfile('C:\\Users\\Documents\\error.log','C:\\Users\\Documents\' + datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S") + '.log')
```

**UPDATE**
Forgot to add the second datetime to the statement

```
import shutil
import datetime
shutil.copyfile('C:\\Users\\Documents\\error.log','C:\\Users\\Documents\' + datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S") + '.log')
```

Comment: error                                                                                                Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "checking.py", line 19, in <module>
    shutil.copyfile('C:\\Users\\Documents\\error.log','C:\\Users\\Documents\\' + d
atetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S") + '.txt')
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'now'

Comment: i think the  strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")  is causing problem